# Python Compare Tokenized Lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sparse-matrix

I need the fastest-possible solution to this problem as it will be applied to a huge data set:

Given this master list:

```
m=['abc','bcd','cde','def']
```

...and this reference list of lists:

```
r=[['abc','def'],['bcd','cde'],['abc','def','bcd']]
```

I'd like to compare each list within r to the master list (m) and generate a new list of lists. This new object will have a 1 for matches based on the order in m and 0 for non-matches. So the new object (list of lists) will always have the lists of the same length as m.
Here's what I would expect based on m and r above:

```
[[1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1]]
```

Because the first element of r is `['abc','def']` and has a match
with the 1st and 4th elements of m, the result is then `[1,0,0,1]`.

Here's my approach so far (probably way too slow and is missing zeros):

```
output=[]
for i in r:
    output.append([1 for x in m if x in i])
```

resulting in:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension like this:

```
>>> m = ['abc','bcd','cde','def']
>>> r = [['abc','def'],['bcd','cde'],['abc','def','bcd']]
>>> [[1 if mx in rx else 0 for mx in m] for rx in r]
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Also, you could shorten the `1 if ... else 0` using `int(...)`, and you can convert the sublists of `r` to `set`, so that the individual `mx in rx` lookups are faster.

```
>>> [[int(mx in rx) for mx in m] for rx in r]
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
>>> [[int(mx in rx) for mx in m] for rx in map(set, r)]
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

While `int(...)` is a bit shorter than `1 if ... else 0`, it also seems to be slower, so you probably should not use that. Converting the sublists of `r` to `set` prior to the repeated lookup should speed things up for longer lists, but for you very short example lists, it's in fact slower than the naive approach.

```
>>> %timeit [[1 if mx in rx else 0 for mx in m] for rx in r]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.74 µs per loop
>>> %timeit [[int(mx in rx) for mx in m] for rx in r]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.07 µs per loop
>>> %timeit [[1 if mx in rx else 0 for mx in m] for rx in map(set, r)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.82 µs per loop
```

For longer lists, using `set` becomes faster, as would be expected:

```
>>> m = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(50)]
>>> r = [[random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(20)]
>>> %timeit [[1 if mx in rx else 0 for mx in m] for rx in r]
1000 loops, best of 3: 412 µs per loop
>>> %timeit [[1 if mx in rx else 0 for mx in m] for rx in map(set, r)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 208 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach using [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with one loop -

```
np.array([np.in1d(m,i) for i in r]).astype(int)
```

With explicit-loop it would look something like this -

```
out = np.empty((len(r),len(m)),dtype=int)
for i,item in enumerate(r):
    out[i] = np.in1d(m,item)
```

We can use `dtype=bool` for memory and performance.

Sample run -

```
In [18]: m
Out[18]: ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def']

In [19]: r
Out[19]: [['abc', 'def'], ['bcd', 'cde'], ['abc', 'def', 'bcd']]

In [20]: np.array([np.in1d(m,i) for i in r]).astype(int)
Out[20]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

If `r` had lists with equal lengths, we could have used a fully vectorized approach.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

You want to add `1` if the `x` is in `i` and `0` if it is not, for every `x` in `m`.

So the script would look like it sounds: `1 if x in i else 0` as condition, `for x in m`:

```
output = [[1 if x in i else 0 for x in m] for i in r]
print(output)
```

Results with

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Without `numpy`*, you may do it using *nested list comprehension* as:

```
>>> m = ['abc','bcd','cde','def']
>>> r = [['abc','def'],['bcd','cde'],['abc','def','bcd']]

>>> [[int(mm in rr) for mm in m] for rr in r]
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Actually you do not need the type-casting to `int` because Python treats `False` as `0` and `True` as `1`. Also, using `bool` value is more memory efficient. Hence, you expression will look like:

```
>>> [[mm in rr for mm in m] for rr in r]
[[True, False, False, True], [False, True, True, False], [True, True, False, True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing to the rescue!

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def matcher(qIn, qOut):
    m = set(['abc','bcd','cde','def'])
    for i,L in iter(qIn.get, None):
        answer = [1 if e in m else 0 for e in L]
        qOut.put((i,answer))


def main(L):
    qIn, qOut = [mp.Queue() for _ in range(2)]
    procs = [mp.Process(target=matcher, args=(qIn, qOut)) for _ in range(mp.cpu_count()-1)]
    for p in procs: p.start()

    numElems = len(L)
    for t in enumerate(L): qIn.put(t)
    for p in procs: qIn.put(None)

    done = 0
    while done < numElems:
        i,answer = qIn.get()
        L[i] = answer
        done += 1

    for p in procs: p.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = [['abc','def'],['bcd','cde'],['abc','def','bcd']]
    main(L)
    # now L looks like the required output
```