# Fastest way to compare arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, shingles

Extending from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665795/python-compare-tokenized-lists/40665877#40665877), I need the *fastest possible* solution to this:

Given the following:

```
m=['abc','bcd','cde','def']
r=[['abc','def'],['bcd','cde'],['abc','def','bcd']]
```

I'd like to edit these objects (or produced new objects) such that for each element in list m, if it exists less than 2 times across all the lists of r, the element is removed from m and also from wherever it occurs in r.

So the result of the above would look like this:

```
['abc','bcd','def']
```

...because 'cde' is only found once in r.

Even better would be this:

```
[2, 2, 1, 2]
```

...or a count of frequencies of elements in m across lists in r.
Then, based on the number, I could edit the lists in r based on the index of the output if the value meets a certain criteria.

So for example, remove index i of each list in r if i <2 or >100.

There is a round-about way to do this, but it is slower than molasses in January:

My starting point is that this:

```
[[1 if mx in rx else 0 for mx in m] for rx in map(set, r)]
```

will produce this:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by "remove from `m` and everywhere in `r`" it seems like you want it to be extracted for other use - correct? seems like an important distinction.

Comment: Rather than get hung up on the absolute fastest method, off the top of my head I'd do flatten list `r`, sort the flattened list, then count the number of consecutive identical entries and lookup `m` to find if you keep the entry or not.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen - Yes, that is important. I don't need the elements after they are removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a line to get the counts:

```
print [sum([1 for _r in r if _m in _r]) for _m in m]
```

It gives the same result, you have written:

```
[2, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: A great start. All I need to do now is be able to use the index of the 1 in the resulting list (index=2) to tell the original list that 'cde' (index location 2) needs to be removed from all sub lists, so the result is r=[['abc','def'],['bcd'],['abc','def','bcd']]. I'd like to also do the same if a resulting value were >100.

Comment: I'll add a follow-up question based on my comment above.

Comment: any way to speed up your solution? I have a large set of data and while it runs in 3 micro seconds on my sample data, it takes a while with a large data set. Thanks for any help you can provide.